# Can some people be selectively psycopathic/sociopathic towards a specific race/ethnicity of people?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, personality, evolutionary-psychology

Psycopaths tend to display remorselessbess while normal people don't.

But imagine 18th century USA, where Slaves were considered lower than animals.

Or consider, a modern day college group, where there are "cool kids" (rich, sophisticated, socially charismatic) and tbe "undesirables" (mediocre intelligence, poor and rustic).

In both of these cases, many people would show a lack of remorse towards the slaves and undesirables while behaving normally with other people.

Does this point to selective psycopathy? Can we truly classify the people here (those who are judging) as being g psychopathic?

Answer (score -1):

psychopathy is not aggression. Psychopathy is a personality disorder that is many things, which includes, but is not limited to, a lack of remorse, for example. A "cool kid" or a white person in the slave era are not psychopaths, they commit these actions for many societal, personal, and psychological reasons that could or could not be diagnosed into several different categories. psychopathy isn't "doing bad things", do not confuse the two. Also, no, discrimination is not psychopathy either.